# I wrote a program that prompts the user to enter a 5x5 array and shows the sum of the rows and columns. Any Idea How I can make this better?

Tags: c

First post !

So I am learning C programming by the book of King. I am at chapter 8, Array. One question in the book is like this :

> Write a program that reads a 5x5 array of integers and then prints the row sums and the column sums.
>
> Example:
>
> Enter row 1 : 1 1 1 1 1
>
> enter row 2 : 1 1 1 1 1
>
> enter row 3 : 1 1 1 1 1
>
> enter row 4 : 1 1 1 1 1
>
> enter row 5 : 1 1 1 1 1
>
> Sum of rows : 5 5 5 5 5
> Sum of columns : 5 5 5 5 5

This is what I got. The program works except for one bug : It won't prompt the user to enter the next row. The user needs to input all the numbers at one time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
int main (void)

{
int z[N][N] ;
int a,b,d,c= 0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,c2= 0,e2=0,f2=0,g2=0,h2=0 ; 

printf("enter rows\n");
     
     for (b=0; b<N; b++)
    {
               for (a=0; a<N; a++)
                { 
                scanf("%d", &z[a][b]);
                }
    }

    for (d=0; d<N; d++)

    {
        c += z[d][0];
        e += z[d][1];
        f += z[d][2];
        g += z[d][3];
        h += z[d][4];
    
    
    }
    for (d=0; d<N; d++)

    {
        c2 += z[0][d];
        e2 += z[1][d];
        f2 += z[2][d];
        g2 += z[3][d];
        h2 += z[4][d];
    
    
    }
printf("total of rows is %d %d %d %d %d\n", c,e,f,g,h);
printf("total of columns is %d %d %d %d %d\n", c2,e2,f2,g2,h2);

/*

    for (b=0; b<N; b++)
    {
          for (a=0; a<N; a++)
          printf("%d", z[a][b]);          
          { 
          printf("\n");
          }
    }
*/
}
```

The main question is : How can I add the numbers more efficiently ?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &z[a][b]);` should'nt this be `z[b][a]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add numbers more efficiently (well, actually, you can, but you do **not** want to, it's huge *premature optimization*).

However, you **can** simplify your program:

```
for (d=0; d<N; d++)

{
    c += z[d][0];
    e += z[d][1];
    f += z[d][2];
    g += z[d][3];
    h += z[d][4];


}
for (d=0; d<N; d++)

{
    c2 += z[0][d];
    e2 += z[1][d];
    f2 += z[2][d];
    g2 += z[3][d];
    h2 += z[4][d];


}

// becomes

int sumrows[N] = {}, sumcols[N] = {};
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (d = 0; d < N; ++d)
        sumrows[i] += z[d][i];
        sumcols[i] += z[i][d];
    }
}
```

About your bug, you can use `printf` inside the first loop:

```
printf("enter rows\n");

 for (b=0; b<N; b++)
{
           for (a=0; a<N; a++)
            { 
            scanf("%d", &z[a][b]);
            }
}

// becomes

for (b = 0; b < N; ++b) {
    printf("Enter row %d", b + 1);
    for (a = 0; a < N; ++a) {
        scanf("%d", &z[a][b]);
    }
}
```

Also note it is usually considered best practice to index in [y][x] while here you are indexing in [x][y]. This has little impact though, but may unsettle developers used to this convention.

Comment: Don't you think `z[a][b]` will input data column wise.

Comment: Yes it will, hence my two last sentences !

Comment: But the input is given row wise and when the rows are different, the data would be actually transpose of what is expected.

Comment: Which is precisely why the sumrows and sumcols are actually implictly transpose of what is expected by the routine-driven developer. Let's always keep an open mind!

Comment: well, then i don't think there is any point discussing it now, the good thing is we both know what is happening.cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (the more efficient way)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int num, i, j;
   int row[5] = {0};
   int column[5] = {0};

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        scanf("%d", &num);
        row[i] = row[i] + num;
        column[j] = column[j] + num;     
     }
   }

   // print the result here
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      printf("\nSum of row %d: %d", i, row[i]);

   printf("\n");

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      printf("\nSum of column %d: %d", i, column[i]);

   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should check the return value of scan as well